# How do I clear a type error when looping over object?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am trying to loop over an array of objects that I have typed. It is possible for the values to be different types depending on the api return, either a boolean, string, or object. I am using vue 3, ts, and this is in a store file in Pinia

Here is the error I am getting in my code:

Property 'field_gid' does not exist on type 'string | boolean | { gid: string; name: string; project_gid: string; } | { field_gid: string; value_type: string; text_value: string; truncated?: string | undefined; } | { gid: string; field_gid: string; resource_type: string; color: string; name: string; } | [] | { ...; }[]'.
Property 'field_gid' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Here is the code where I am getting the error:

```
export interface Card {
    gid: string;
    name: string;
    notes: string;
    permalink_url: string;
    asana_modified_at: string,
    is_cqi: boolean;
    is_released: boolean;
    is_spotlight: boolean;
    section: cardSection;
    source_link: boolean | customTextField;
    review_area: boolean | customTextField;
    detailed_feedback: boolean | customTextField;
    recommendation: boolean | customTextField;
    action: boolean | customTextField;
    responsible_office: boolean | customSelectField;
    academic_year: boolean | customSelectField;
    course: boolean | customSelectField;
    status: boolean | customSelectField;
    feedback_sources: boolean | [] | customSelectField[];
    feedback_sources_concat: string;
    collaborating_offices: boolean | [] | customSelectField[];
    collaborating_offices_concat: string;
    communication_channels: boolean | [] | customSelectField[];
    communication_channels_concat: string;
}

export interface customTextField {
    field_gid: string;
    value_type: string;
    text_value: string;
    truncated?: string;
}

export interface customSelectField {
    gid: string;
    field_gid: string;
    resource_type: string;
    color: string;
    name: string;
}

this.filteredCards.forEach((card) => {
                    for(const prop in card) {
                        if(typeof card[prop as keyof Card] !== 'boolean' && typeof card[prop as keyof Card] !== 'string') {
                            if(card[prop as keyof Card].field_gid === checkedFilter.parentId && card[prop as keyof Card].gid === checkedFilter.id) {
                                filteredArr.push(card)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
```

I tried to do a typeof check to make sure they were not a string or boolean but it isn't clearing the type error. I am still pretty new to ts so probably a simple error.

Comment: ChatGPT gives an answer to that. Cannot post it because it would get me banned. But basically you cannot access card[prop}.field_gid because only a few properties of card are of type customSelectField which has .field_gid